# Highslide.js How to enable disabled arrow-button

Tags: javascript, highslide

I have site with galleries. Each gallery has ajax pagination. I have made highslide show pictures from next or previous page. When you reach the last image on the page and press right arrow key on keyboard the list of images will update and highslide will reopens with new images automaticaly. I can press right button on keyboard but can't click arrow because it is disabled.

I would like enable disabled arrows but depending on some conditions. This is possible?

Thank you.

Comment: It’s difficult to answer your question without knowing how you are updating the list of images. I also need to see the code for your ajax pagination. Do you have a live page where I can see this?

Comment: Here is the [gallery page](http://tattooa.ru/portfolio/tattoos/)

Here is the [highslide config](http://tattooa.ru/wp-content/plugins/highslide/highslide.cfg.js). Check there hs.previousOrNext function.

And here is [nextgen js](http://tattooa.ru/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.js) Here check hichslide_ajax_navigation function which is a little bit modified version of ngg_ajax_navigation.

Comment: I don't know what exectly you need to know. List of images updates simply by ajax. After that i check possible directions with custom function directions.check(). Than i call hs.updateAnchors(). Don't know is it helpful.

Comment: I can see that you’re using code from the [Highslide cross-page mod](http://highslide.com/studies/cross-page-1.html) for the Next/Previous buttons, but I think you skipped the important part of the code – the part that starts with `hs.Slideshow.prototype.checkFirstAndLast`. I don’t know if this will work together with your code since everything in the cross-page mod is written to work with hs.pages, where the pages for the pagination is set in the js code (no ajax). I have to set up a Wordpress installation with Nexgen gallery to test this, so I need more time before I can give you an answer.

Comment: O thank you very much for pointing me to hs.Slideshow.prototype.checkFirstAndLast. I simply check is there on page next and previous buttons (by id and class) and give to relative variables true or false. Now I have modified a little bit checkFirstAndLast function to respect this variables so my issue is solved. Again thank you very much.